# Web Automation using Python/Selenium to upload a file through Dojo FileUploader

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Generally, it's simple to make automation using Selenium to upload a file and there are many solutions for it.

But,
what I am facing for trouble is to implement web automation to upload a file through Dojo FileUploader.

```
    <div class="ux uploader dnd fluid webDriver_uploader enforce-validity-marker-class mtc-uploader" data-dojo-attach-event="click:_onClickDomNode,drop:_onDropDomNode,dragover:_onDragOverDomNode,dragleave:_onDragLeaveDomNode,mouseenter:_onMouseEnterDomNode,mouseleave:_onMouseLeaveDomNode" id="Uploader_0" lang="en" widgetid="Uploader_0">
      <i class="upload icon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></i>
      <input type="file" name="">
      <button type="button" class="ux button" data-dojo-attach-point="browseButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="blur:_onBlurBrowseButtonNode,click:_onClickBrowseButtonNode,focus:_onFocusBrowseButtonNode">Choose File
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="ux basic icon button hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="removeButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="click:_onClickRemoveButtonNode" title="Remove File">
        <i class="trash icon">
          <span class="description">Remove
          </span>
        </i>
      </button>
      <div class="placeholder label" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="click:_onClickLabelNode">or drag and drop here
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Please check this screenshot]

I've tried to control the file open dialog after clicking the Choose File button. But it seems like it's impossible to interact between the selenium and file open dialog.

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can interacts only with browser and when choose file button get clicked it will open file explorer ( which is in OS).

Workaround : instead of opening file explorer popup you can pass directly file path to selenium which it can upload automatically.
for Example : driver.findElementById().send_keys('filepath')

also you can use PyWinAuto to interact with file explorer for windows.(https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).